# Regex Capture Group with 2 names

Tags: regex

I would like to set a value for more than 1 capture group at the same time. I originally have this:

```
^(\/path\/)((?<ID>)[^\/]*)
```

But I would like to make it so that we can set the same value to more than 1 capture group at the same time. So I would like to do something like this:

```
^(\/path\/)((?<ID>and?<ID2>)[^\/]*)
```

so if we have this string: /path/123, then capture group ID would be 123, and capture group ID2 would also be 123

Comment: How about `(?<ID>(?<ID2>[^\/]*))`?